# Interest accrued on $2600 security deposit for 5 years

Tags: interest-rate, rental-property, new-york, escrow

I paid a $2600 security deposit.  We were there 5 years.  What should my deposit have earned in interest in NY?This particular landlord never gave us any information on an escrow account.  He owns more than 6 units.  I do not trust him.

Comment: Does your rental agreement say anything about accruing interest on your security deposit?

Answer (score 7):

The rules regarding interest on security deposits are a state or even local set of laws.

For example for [New York State](https://ag.ny.gov/sites/default/files/tenants_rights.pdf):

> Landlords of buildings with six or more apartments must put all
>   security deposits in New York bank accounts earning interest at the
>   prevailing rate. Each tenant must be informed in writing of the bank’s
>   name and address and the amount of the deposit. Landlords are entitled
>   to collect annual administrative expenses of one percent of the
>   deposit. All other interest earned on the deposits belongs to the
>   tenants. Tenants must be given the option of having this interest paid
>   to them annually, applied to rent, or paid at the end of the lease
>   term. If the building has fewer than six apartments, a landlord who
>   voluntarily places the security deposits in an interest bearing bank
>   account must also follow these rules.

The "prevailing rate" requirement in combination with the allowable 1% administrative fee will make it likely that little or no interest will be owed to the tenant.

Now if you mean NY city, that may have a different set of laws.